# Strapi Nuxt 3 Cookie Disappears on page reload

Tags: strapi, nuxtjs3

Using https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/ to manage user authentication.

On user success login, the cookie gets set. However, on page refresh the cookie is deleted. Also, the expiry doesn't appear be to taking place. This is my nuxt.config. Any ideas.

On the following post they suggested upgrading strapi and nuxt, which i've tried, with the same outcome - https://github.com/nuxt-modules/strapi/pull/354

Version
@nuxtjs/strapi: 4.13.6
nuxt: 3.7.4

I my "auth.ts" middleware i have the following -

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {

  const user = useStrapiUser()
    
  if (!user.value) {
    return navigateTo('/login')
  }

})
```

nuxt.config.ts looks like this -

```
runtimeConfig: {
  strapi: {
    url: 'https://login.7da2-202-129-81-163.ngrok-free.app',
    prefix: '/api',
    version: 'v4',
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30days login time
    },
    cookieName: 'strapi_jwt',
 },
}
```

I have also tried assigning a maxAge programmatically after login, but no dice.

```
const { login } = useStrapiAuth()

try {
  const response = await login({ identifier: identifier, password: password })
  await useCookie('strapi_jwt', { 
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    path: '/'
  })            

  return response
} catch (e) {            
  throw e
}
```

Any ideas?